# Dynamic value of columns Datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

i create [datatable](https://datatables.net/), i want create dynamically columns data.

my init datatable looks like this :

```
var columnsData = [
    {data: 'name'},
    {data: 'phone'}
];
var dtable = $('#dtable').DataTable({
     serverSide : true,
     ajax : '/data',
     columns : columnsData,
});
```

in some condition, make columns data changed. i don't have solution for that.

example columns what i want to change :

```
columnsData = [
    {data: 'name'},
    {data: 'address'}
]
```

i was try

```
dtable.columns.data( columnsData ).load();
dtable.columns.data( columnsData ).draw();
```

but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function to recreate the data table with changes in structure.

```
function getDT() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/data',
      success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        columnNames = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
        for (var i in columnNames) {
          columns.push({data: columnNames[i], 
                    title: capitalizeFirstLetter(columnNames[i])});
        }
        $('#dtable').DataTable( {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '/data',
            columns: columns
        } );
      }
    });
}
```

please find the complete implementation on [Example](http://live.datatables.net/qimukefe/1/edit)